# Database connection in PhpStorm results in java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1

Tags: java, jdbc, phpstorm

I'm trying to connect my database to my project (in PhpStorm), so that I have autocomplete.

Steps that I do to get the error :

- Open the database panel, and add a `MySQL DataSource`
- Fill every field
- Click `TEST CONNECTION` button

I've filled correctly every field (host, database, user, password) in the Database feature

- Host: `s00vl9944624.fr.net.intra`
- Database: `animationqrc`
- User: `animationqrc`
- URL (built by PhpStorm): `jdbc:mysql://s00vl9944624.fr.net.intra:3306/animationqrc`

The error is :

> java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
>     java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

The problem is that, when I use myself a Java class that only tries to connect to the server and print rows from a table, it works.

```java
import java.sql.*;

class MysqlCon{
public static void main(String args[]){
  try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://s00vl9944624.fr.net.intra:3306/pilconquete?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","*user*","*pass*");
//here sonoo is the database name, root is the username and root is the password
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from Admin_list");

while(rs.next())
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));

con.close();

}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}

}
}
```

```sh
"C:\Users\b96297\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2018.2.3\jre64\bin\java" MysqlCon  
Thu Sep 20 16:14:02 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.  
3  497764  Xavier *******
```

Even when I add PhpStorm default parameter (that you can see in the log below), except classpath.

```
"C:\Users\b96297\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2018.2.3\jre64\bin\java" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 MysqlCon
```

When I add the classpath parameter, Java doesn't find my class.

I'm using Win7 x64, PhpStorm 2018.2.3 (was also failing in 2017.3.3). I'm at work, so network restrictions might apply, firewall. And I don't have admin rights on my laptop.

Thanks for your help

---

**EDIT:**

From PhpStorm log :

```
2018-09-20 15:54:25,481 [  81612]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - "C:\Users\b96297\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2018.2.3\jre64\bin\java" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\b96297\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2018.2.3\lib\util.jar;C:\Users\b96297\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2018.2.3\lib\trove4j.jar;C:\Users\b96297\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2018.2.3\lib\groovy-all-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\b96297\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2018.2.3\plugins\DatabaseTools\lib\jdbc-console.jar;C:\Users\b96297\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2018.2.3\plugins\DatabaseTools\lib\dekaf-single-2.0.0.372.jar;C:\Users\b96297\.PhpStorm\config\jdbc-drivers\MySQL Connector\J\5.1.46\mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar;C:\Users\b96297\Downloads\mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar" com.intellij.database.remote.RemoteJdbcServer com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
2018-09-20 15:54:25,701 [  81832]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary. 
2018-09-20 15:54:26,310 [  82441]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Port/ID: 30227/RemoteDriverImpl3260ec8e 
2018-09-20 15:54:46,310 [ 102441]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - java.rmi.NotBoundException: _DEAD_HAND_ 
2018-09-20 15:54:46,310 [ 102441]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:209) 
2018-09-20 15:54:46,310 [ 102441]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer.start(RemoteServer.java:96) 
2018-09-20 15:54:46,310 [ 102441]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.database.remote.RemoteJdbcServerBase.setupAndStart(RemoteJdbcServerBase.java:20) 
2018-09-20 15:54:46,310 [ 102441]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.database.remote.RemoteJdbcServer.main(RemoteJdbcServer.java:14) 
2018-09-20 15:54:47,334 [ 103465]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - The cook failed to start due to java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect 
2018-09-20 15:54:47,335 [ 103466]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Process finished with exit code 1 
2018-09-20 15:54:47,339 [ 103470]   WARN - lij.database.util.ErrorHandler - java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

---

- I've tried setting *java.rmi.server.hostname* to different IPs (my own, server's hostname, server's IP)
- I've tried from the bundled java that comes with PhpStorm
- I can log to the server with *mysql* commandline

Comment: I've initially made a comment about "drivers missing" .. but then realised that the error message is actually different to what you will see then (but still -- double check them). Error says "refused to host **127.0.0.1**" and in your Java code you are using domain name. Maybe that has something to do? Another suggestion (not super sure on relevancy to this error but still) -- try deleting the connection, re-opening project and adding connection again.

Comment: That popup is from the PHP storm feature to connect to the database, and apparently you've configured that to connect to the wrong database (host 127.0.0.1 instead of that ...fr.net.intra). Also for the future: please don't post images of code or errors, post errors as text (possibly as quote or code block) and post code as a code formatted text block.

Comment: @LazyOne I've updated my post to include the origin of the **127.0.0.1**. I've already tried deleting and recreating the DB connection.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've corrected the formatting of my post. I didn't configure my hostname wrong, PhpStorm is adding *java.rmi.server.hostname* (defaults to localhost in IPV4 format) parameter when it executes the connection

Comment: What does _"when it executes the connection"_ mean? You don 'execute' a connection. Also, as far as I can tell that error is **not** from your Java code, but from using a database connection within PHP storm itself. Please describe the exact steps that result in that error. It is also entirely possible that this error has nothing to do with using the database connection, as RMI is usually not involved in creating database connections, in which case the problem might be something else entirely.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I meant *"When PhpStorm executes its portion of code that try to connect to the database"*, so yeah, within its own code.
Yes, the error is not from my code.

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with how IntelliJ/PHPStorm communicates between its components (isolated in separate Java processes). Unfortunately I have no clue what the fix would be. Possibly this is a Windows firewall issue that prevents IntelliJ from talking to itself.

Comment: Could you check the allowed apps config of Windows Firewall for the OpenJDK Platform Binary for your PHP Storm install (see its details, path should be `C:\Users\b96297\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2018.2.3` based on your logs), and see if it's allowed for private (and maybe public)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel On a computer where I'm admin (a remote computer with same network rules), I changed the firewall, and yes it works. But I'm not admin on my work laptop. Thanks for your help. I will close my post

Comment: I've summarized my comments in an answer, it may be helpful to leave this question as is; possibly other people run into this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize my comments, it seems that PhpStorm uses separate Java processes to isolate database access from the rest of the application. It looks like communication between these two processes (using RMI, Remote Method Invocation) is not possible.

This is possibly a firewall issue. Given you're using Windows, check the Windows Firewall settings under allowed apps config for the OpenJDK Platform Binary for your PhpStorm install (see its details, path should be `C:\Users\b96297\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2018.2.3\jre64\bin\java` in your case), and enable *Private* access (in some cases, you may need to try *Public* as well). This will allow the Java processes to communicate using RMI.

If you can't find the OpenJDK Platform Binary in the firewall configuration, add the `java.exe` from the `jre64\bin` folder of the PhpStorm install and configure it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try with my corporate sysadmins to add the OpenJDK to the firewall allowed list.

Answer (score 1):

After discussing with @MarkRotteveel and Dmitry Tronin | Support Engineer at JetBrains,
I've learned and discovered a few things:

- Adding OpenJDK (PhpStorm bundled JDK) to the list of Allowed Programs in Windows Firewall works.
- There's an ongoing ticket that the support linked me : [Ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-6604)